# How do i get space between of elements when using grid in css

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm new to `grid` and am trying to get space between two elements. While using `align-content: space-between;` i get the expected result but when I use `justify-content: space-between;` nothing happens

How would I change the CSS to get the expected result?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(143, 123, 123, 0.4);
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 60%;
  width: 50%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-content: space-between;
  /* below is the problem that I am having, I assume that there is supposed to be space between the elements but its not working */
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container .brightness {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: black;
}

.container .saturation {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: black;
}

.container .inversion {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: black;
}

.container .grayscale {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>stackoverflow questions</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="brightness"></div>
    <div class="saturation"></div>
    <div class="inversion"></div>
    <div class="grayscale"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "*I am trying to get space between two elements*" - What do you mean with this? Please explain what you want to do with this "space", what is the expected result?

Comment: use the correct property to create space: [grid-gap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap). Grid utilizes all available space by default, unlike flexbox. As such there will be no gaps (space) in a grid between the elements.

Comment: I would like two elements to stick to the left margin and the other two elements to stick to the right margin. simmilar to how I have used ```align-content: space-between;``` for two elements to stick to the top and two to the bottom.

Comment: auto instead of 1fr

Answer (score 0):

one thing you can do, add these styles to the saturation and grayscale squares if you want them to be at the end of the container or else if you want to give a custom gap between them you can do so using the gap property.

```
.container .saturation{
        width: 70px;
        height: 70px;
        background-color: black;
        display: grid;
        justify-self: end;
    }

.container .grayscale{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: black;
    display: grid;
    justify-self: end;
}
```

Comment: i have tried that and it is not working...https://jsfiddle.net/camindo/o9rzc1k4/3/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there's a misunderstanding of how `align-content` and `justify-content` work in the context of a grid container.

- align-content works along the block axis (vertically for a row-based grid).
- justify-content works along the inline axis (horizontally for a row-based grid).

In your case, since you have set `grid-template-columns` in your container, it's a row-based grid. Therefore, `align-content: space-between;` will affect the vertical spacing, and `justify-content: space-between;` will not have a visible effect.

If you want space between the columns, you should adjust the `grid-column-gap`  property in your container class:

```
.container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 60%;
  width: 50%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-content: space-between; /* This affects vertical spacing */
  grid-column-gap: 10px; /* Adjust this value to set the horizontal space between columns */
}
```

Comment: It works tho it is not intuitive as I imagined.

Comment: How would You make it, so that all elements touch the side?

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it's working for you! I'm not getting you clearly on `so that all elements touch the side`, kindly describe your specific layout and so I can help you to adjust the CSS accordingly.

Comment: I would like two elements to stick to the left margin and the other two elements to stick to the right margin. simmilar to how I have used align-content: space-between; for two elements to stick to the top and two to the bottom. See how the ```aligncontent``` touches the bottom and topin this fidle https://jsfiddle.net/camindo/o9rzc1k4/14/